# Rails - Stripe::InvalidRequestError, must provide source or customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I'm getting the above error when trying to implement a payment process for my Rails app. This is the error in full -

[image]

I've tried source: stripe_token and source: stripe_charge_id but neither of those work.

Here's what is in my Booking model -

**Booking.rb**

```
   class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :event, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

    before_save :set_price_to_zero_if_free

    def set_price_to_zero_if_free
       self.event.price >= 1    unless self.event.is_free
    end

    def reserve
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        #if valid?

        # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
        #self.total_amount = booking.quantity * event.price

            # Free events don't need to do anything special
            if event.is_free?
            save!

            # Paid events should charge the customer's card
        else

            begin
            charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: total_amount, currency: "gbp", card: stripe_charge_id, description: "Booking number #{id}", items: [{quantity: quantity}])
            self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
            save!
                rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                errors.add(:base, e.message)
            false
            end
        end 
    end
end
```

And my controller -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new

        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        @booking.user = current_user


    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

            if 
                @booking.reserve
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end


    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id)
    end



end
```

I'm a bit stumped on this so any help is appreciated. I've tried various options now but am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the Stripe doc: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge. Your charge request lacks either a `source` or `customer` params.

Personally, I would create a Stripe customer first and pass the customer ID to the charge request.

However, you still have to obtain the user's credit card information first via possibly the Stripe form and use the token Stripe returned as the `source`.

Did you obtain the user credit card information in anyway before performing the charge request?